# Нужно ли выделять запятыми обстоятельственный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

Это обстоятельство не позволяет рассчитать рабочие процессы в динамическом режиме (,) с учетом распределения давления газа по клапанному узлу (,)и учесть поле скоростей течения газа в проточной полости для определения динамического напора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оборот является уточняющим, и его надо обособить.

Сравнить (предложение без оборота):

Это обстоятельство не позволяет рассчитать рабочие процессы в динамическом режиме  и учесть поле скоростей течения газа в проточной полости для определения динамического напора.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, по правилам здесь запятая не нужна, но возможна для того, чтобы немного структурировать записанную фразу и внести ясность в смысл высказывания

Answer (score 0):

Если в динамическом режиме = с учетом распределения давления газа, то запятые нужны. А если это не одно и то же (динамический режим предполагает учет множества параметров), то не нужны.